# Fluentd incorrectly routing logs to its own STDOUT

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I have a GKE cluster, in which I'm using [Fluentd Kubernetes Daemonset v1.14.3](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/) (docker image: `fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.14.3-debian-gcs-1.1`) to collect the logs from certain containers and forward them to a GCS Bucket.

My configuration takes logs from `/var/log/containers/*.log`, filter the containers based on some kubernetes annotations and then upload them to GCS using a [plugin](https://github.com/daichirata/fluent-plugin-gcs).

In most cases, this works correctly, but I'm currently stuck with some weird issue:
certain containers' logs are sometimes printed into `fluentd` own `stdout`. Let me elaborate:

Assume we have a container called `helloworld` which runs `echo "HELLO WORLD"`.
Soon after the container starts, I can see in `fluentd`'s own logs:

```
2022-07-20 13:29:04 +0000 [info]: #0 [in_tail_container_logs] following tail of /var/log/containers/my-pod_my-namespace_helloworld-7e6359514a5601e5ad1823d145fd3b73f7b65648f5cb760f2c1855dabe27d606.log"
...
HELLO WORLD
...
```

This `.log` file contains the standard output of my docker container ("HELLO WORLD" in some json structured format).

Normally, `fluentd` should tail this log, and send the messages to the GCS plugin, which should upload them to the destination bucket. But sometimes, **the logs are printed directly into `fluentd`'s own output, instead of being passed to the plugin.**

I'd appreciate any help to root-cause this issue.

#### Things I've looked into

1. I have increased the verbosity of the logs using `fluentd -vv`, but found nothing relevant.
2. This happens kind of randomly, but only for certain containers. It never happens for some containers, but for others it sometimes does, and sometimes it doesn't.
3. There's nothing special about the containers presenting this issue.
4. We don't have any configuration for `fluentd` to stream the logs to `stdout`. We triple checked this.

The issue happens on a GKE cluster (`1.21.12-gke.1700`).
Below the fluentd configuration being used:

```
<label @FLUENT_LOG>
  <match fluent.**>
    @type null
  </match>
</label>

<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_container_logs
  path /var/log/containers/*.log
  exclude_path ["/var/log/containers/fluentd-*", "/var/log/containers/fluentbit-*", "/var/log/containers/kube-*", "/var/log/containers/pdsci-*", "/var/log/containers/gke-*"]
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-containers.log.pos
  tag "kubernetes.*"
  refresh_interval 1s
  read_from_head true
  follow_inodes true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</source>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type kubernetes_metadata
  @id filter_kube_metadata
  kubernetes_url "#{'https://' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST') + ':' + ENV.fetch('KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT') + '/api'}"
  verify_ssl true
  ca_file "#{ENV['KUBERNETES_CA_FILE']}"
  watch false  # Don't watch for changes in container metadata
  de_dot false  # Don't replace dots in labels and annotations
  skip_labels false
  skip_master_url true
  skip_namespace_metadata true
  annotation_match ["app.*\/log-.+"]
</filter>

<filter kubernetes.**>
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key $.kubernetes.namespace_name
    pattern /^my-namespace$/
  </regexp>
  <regexp>
    key $['kubernetes']['labels']['example.com/collect']
    pattern /^yes$/
  </regexp>
</filter>

<match kubernetes.**>
  # docs: https://github.com/daichirata/fluent-plugin-gcs
  @type gcs
  @id out_gcs
  project "#{ENV['GCS_BUCKET_PROJECT']}"
  bucket "#{ENV.fetch('GCS_BUCKET_PROJECT')"
  object_key_format %Y%m%d/%H%M/%{$.kubernetes.pod_name}_${$.kubernetes.container_name}_${$.docker.container_id}/%{index}.%{file_extension}
  store_as json

  <buffer time,$.kubernetes.pod_name,$.kubernetes.container_name,$.docker.container_id>
    @type file
    path /var/log/fluentd-buffers/gcs.buffer
    timekey 30
    timekey_wait 5
    timekey_use_utc true # use utc
    chunk_limit_size 1MB
    flush_at_shutdown true
  </buffer>

  <format>
    @type json
  </format>

</match>
```